# Xcode not found when installing Ruby with RVM

Tags: ruby, xcode, rvm

I'm trying to install rvm and ruby. I've got rvm installed, but whenever I run `rvm install x` it fails. I look in make.log and I see the following:

```
[2020-08-07 15:49:26] __rvm_make
__rvm_make () 
{ 
    \make "$@" || return $?
}
current path: /Users/hine/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.5
PATH=/usr/local/opt/coreutils/bin:/usr/local/opt/pkg-config/bin:/usr/local/opt/libtool/bin:/usr/local/opt/automake/bin:/usr/local/opt/autoconf/bin:/Users/hine/.cargo/bin:/Users/hine/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:/Users/hine/.fastlane/bin:/Users/hine/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/hine/istio-1.0.2/bin:/Users/hine/.rvm/bin
command(2): __rvm_make -j4
++ make -j4
    BASERUBY = /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby --disable=gems
    CC = gcc
    LD = ld
    LDSHARED = gcc -dynamiclib
    CFLAGS = -O3 -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wdivision-by-zero -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wwrite-strings -Wmissing-noreturn -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-overlength-strings -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-self-assign -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-unused-value -Wunused-variable -Wextra-tokens   -fno-common -pipe 
    XCFLAGS = -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector-strong -fno-strict-overflow -fvisibility=hidden -DRUBY_EXPORT -DCANONICALIZATION_FOR_MATHN
    CPPFLAGS = -I/usr/local/opt/libyaml/include -I/usr/local/opt/libksba/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -I/usr/local/opt/zlib/include -I/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/include -D_XOPEN_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE -D_DARWIN_UNLIMITED_SELECT -D_REENTRANT   -I. -I.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18 -I./include -I. -I./enc/unicode/12.1.0 
    DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-undefined,dynamic_lookup -Wl,-multiply_defined,suppress -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libksba/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib -L/usr/local/opt/zlib/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl@1.1/lib -install_name /Users/hine/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.5/lib/libruby.2.6.dylib -compatibility_version 2.6 -current_version 2.6.5  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  -fstack-protector-strong -framework Security -framework Foundation  
    SOLIBS = -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lobjc
    LANG = en_US.UTF-8
    LC_ALL = 
    LC_CTYPE = 
Configured with: --prefix=/Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode 10.2.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode 10.2.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.14.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode 10.2.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
compiling ./main.c
compiling dmydln.c
compiling miniinit.c
compiling dmyext.c
compiling miniprelude.c
translating probes probes.d
compiling ast.c
compiling bignum.c
. ./vm_opts.h
compiling class.c
compiling compar.c
compiling compile.c
compiling complex.c
compiling cont.c
compiling debug.c
compiling debug_counter.c
compiling dir.c
compiling dln_find.c
compiling encoding.c
compiling enum.c
compiling enumerator.c
compiling error.c
compiling eval.c
compiling file.c
compiling gc.c
compiling hash.c
compiling inits.c
compiling io.c
compiling iseq.c
compiling load.c
compiling marshal.c
compiling math.c
making mjit_config.h
compiling mjit_compile.c
compiling node.c
compiling numeric.c
compiling object.c
compiling pack.c
compiling parse.c
compiling proc.c
compiling process.c
compiling random.c
compiling range.c
compiling rational.c
compiling re.c
compiling regcomp.c
compiling regenc.c
compiling regerror.c
compiling regexec.c
compiling regparse.c
compiling regsyntax.c
compiling ruby.c
compiling safe.c
compiling signal.c
compiling sprintf.c
compiling st.c
compiling strftime.c
compiling string.c
compiling struct.c
compiling symbol.c
compiling thread.c
compiling time.c
compiling transcode.c
compiling transient_heap.c
compiling util.c
compiling variable.c
./revision.h unchanged
compiling vm.c
compiling vm_backtrace.c
compiling vm_dump.c
compiling vm_trace.c
compiling ./missing/explicit_bzero.c
compiling ./missing/setproctitle.c
compiling addr2line.c
compiling dmyenc.c
config.status: creating ruby-runner.h
compiling dln.c
compiling localeinit.c
compiling prelude.c
compiling array.c
compiling mjit.c
assembling coroutine/amd64/Context.S
compiling enc/ascii.c
compiling enc/us_ascii.c
compiling enc/unicode.c
compiling enc/utf_8.c
compiling enc/trans/newline.c
compiling version.c
building rb_mjit_header.h
linking miniruby
rb_mjit_header.h updated
generating encdb.h
building .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.5.h
./miniruby -I./lib -I. -I.ext/common  ./tool/transform_mjit_header.rb "gcc " rb_mjit_header.h .ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.5.h
encdb.h updated
./tool/ifchange "--timestamp=.rbconfig.time" rbconfig.rb rbconfig.tmp
rbconfig.rb updated
generating enc.mk
creating verconf.h
verconf.h updated
compiling loadpath.c
making srcs under enc
/bin/sh: /Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode: No such file or directory
make: *** [srcs-enc] Error 127
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....

Transforming external functions to static:
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aset' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_opt_struct_aref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_equal_opt' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: changing definition of 'rb_vm_search_method_slowpath' to declaration
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_push_frame' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_cref_new_toplevel' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making external definition of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_rewrite_cref' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_frame_block_handler' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_block_ep_update' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_vm_ep_local_ep' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sigbits
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'Init_vm_stack_canary' static inline
transform_mjit_header: making declaration of 'rb_eql_opt' static inline
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospi
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincospif
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincos
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sincosf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormall
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormald
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnormalf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_signbitf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnand
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isnanf
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfl
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinfd
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isinff
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitel
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinited
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __inline_isfinitef
transform_mjit_header: SKIPPED to transform __sputc
ln -sf ../../../.ext/include/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.5.h include/ruby-2.6.0/x86_64-darwin18/rb_mjit_min_header-2.6.5.h
++ return 2
```

tl;dir:

```
/bin/sh: /Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode: No such file or directory
make: *** [srcs-enc] Error 127
```

So this is correct that Xcode is not at Downloads/Xcode. It's actually at Downloads/Xcode 10.2.

How do I make rvm know that?

Comment: Whatever you did to configure it to look for Xcode in `/Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode 10.2.app`, redo those steps but this time wrap it in quotes like `"/Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode 10.2.app"` or escape the spaces like `/Users/hine/Downloads/Xcode\ 10.2.app`, then retry.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, before you replied though I tried just changing the name back to Xcode in my Downloads directory then rerunning xcode-select to point to that. That seems to have fixed it.